# Maintaining order of corresponding matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

I have a logistic regression model an I want to create a lift chart to show its efficacy.  To do that I need to order my validation set by descending predicted probability.  This sort is easily done in MATLAB but I need to know how it changes the order of my predictions so that I can re-order the actual values of validation set accordingly, is there a simple way to do this without writing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[As,inds] = sort(A,'descend');
Bs = B(inds);
```

Note that if you have your vectors in a single matrix, you can use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).  For example, if you want to sort a matrix `X` according to the second column:

```
Y = sortrows(X,-2) % -2 means second column, descending
Y1 = Y(:,1);       % first column of X sorted according to X(:,2)
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks!  When it will let me I'll give you the accept for the answer

Comment: @sedavidw Great! no sweat.

Comment: +1 I didn't know there could be a second argument (column) to `sortrows`!

Comment: @LuisMendo And I didn't realize that it needed to be negative for descending.  Glad I just noticed that part of the docs.